# Variable order in interaction terms

Tags: r, glm, interaction, model.matrix

I'm trying to fit a number of linear models as shown below.  It is important that all interaction terms are sorted lexicographically.  Note that the second model is missing the main effect for x.

```
x = rnorm(100)
y = rnorm(100)
z = x + y + rnorm(100)
m1 = glm(z ~ x + y + x:y)
m2 = glm(z ~ y + x:y)
```

The models don't behave as expected with respect to the interaction terms:

```
m1: 
x:y          -0.1565     0.1151  -1.360   0.1770    

m2:
y:x          -0.2776     0.1416  -1.961   0.0528 .
```

I understand that there may be a way to use the interaction() function with the lex.order argument but I can't figure out how or, indeed, whether this is the best way to go.  Advice?

Comment: If you tell R to fit a model including `x:y`, only the interaction will be included. Use `x*y` if you want to add the main effects as well

Comment: See my comment above: the main effect is missing on purpose.  I have two similar models, one without main effect, and I need to be able to have the interaction terms in the same order.  This is not a mistake.

Comment: Then why are they not behaving as expected?

Comment: What is not "as expected" is that the second model is written down as z ~ y + y:x rather than z ~ y + x:y

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, regressing on `y:x` or `x:y` is the same as the variable `y:x` is just the (element-wise) product of `x` and `y`

Comment: You will need to change the order of your predictors, as model.frame arranges them in the order it meets them. So `m2 = glm(z ~  x:y + y)`

Comment: But the coefficients fitted will always be the same..